# Scoring fields - No partial scoring can be entered in the section of fields

Tags: validation-rule, page-validation

I have a section of scoring fields to enter score.
Once a score is entered, it cant be editable by anyone else except Administrator. No Partial Scoring can be done on the fields.
Once they edit one field, they have to edit all the fields.

used below formula, but cant get the partial scoring implemented along with it.

AND(
NOT(ISNEW()),
ISCHANGED(Picklist_Field__c),
NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Picklist_Field__c)))),
$User.ProfileId <> 'Admin profile ID' 
)

Comment: what have you tried so far?  There is no VR knowledge about page layout sections as VR applies to the database (model) layer.

Comment: i tried Validation Rule, but it doesnt work.

Comment: please use [edit] to show what you have tried; a screenshot would be helpful. Please also see [ask] to get the most from the community

Answer (score 0):

How many scoring fields do you have.

Let's say if you have five scoring fields

Score1__c,
Score2__c,
Score3__c,
Score4__c,
Score5__c

You can write a formula to find how many fields are filled. Let's say "scoreCount__c"

```
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Score1__c)), 0, 1) +
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Score2__c)), 0, 1) +
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Score3__c)), 0, 1) +
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Score4__c)), 0, 1) +
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Score5__c)), 0, 1)
```

then you can write a validation rule to force users to fill all the score fields

```
IF(AND(ScoreCount__c > 0, ScoreCount__c < 5), TRUE, FALSE)
```

You can write separate validation rule for checking change

```
AND(
NOT(ISNEW()),
$User.ProfileId <> 'Admin profile ID',
OR(
AND(
ISCHANGED(Score1__c),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Score1__c)))),
AND(
ISCHANGED( Score2__c),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Score2__c)))),
AND(
ISCHANGED( Score3__c),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Score3__c)))),
AND(
ISCHANGED( Score4__c),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Score4__c)))),
AND(
ISCHANGED( Score5__c),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Score5__c))))
)
)
```

Let us know once you try..

Comment: It has almost 20 fields. will let u know ASAP i am done with it.